# argument to 'NSDictionary' method 'dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:' should be an objective-C pointer type, not int

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getLSBGoalList
{
    int userId = [[[AppManager sharedAppManager].userInfo objectForKey:USER_ID] intValue];

    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM tblLBGoal WHERE userId = %d ORDER BY groupId", userId];

    FMResultSet *rs = [database executeQuery:query];
    NSMutableArray *arrLSBGoals = [NSMutableArray array];
    while([rs next])
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:[rs intForColumn:@"lbGoalId"]], @"lbGoalId",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:[rs intForColumn:@"groupId"]], @"groupId",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:[rs intForColumn:@"userId"]], @"userId",
                              [rs stringForColumn:@"uuid"],@"uuid",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:[rs intForColumn:@"dataSyncType"]], @"dataSyncType",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:[rs intForColumn:@"idealValue"]], @"idealValue",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:[rs intForColumn:@"targetValue"]], @"targetValue",nil,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:[rs intForColumn:@"isTargetSet"]], @"isTargetSet",nil];

        [arrLSBGoals addObject:dict];
    }
    return arrLSBGoals;
}
```

I am using the above code and when I analyse my project I got a warning, `Argument to 'NSDictionary' method 'dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:' should be an objective-C pointer type, not int`. Analyser show me the below way to fix it but I can't understand what to do. Can anybody please help me.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `nil` in the line before last:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:[rs intForColumn:@"targetValue"]], @"targetValue",nil,  // here
[NSNumber numberWithInt:[rs intForColumn:@"isTargetSet"]], @"isTargetSet",nil];
```

using the newer Objective-C dictionary literal syntax is much easier to read and doesn't require a terminating `nil`:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
   @"lbGoalId" : @([rs intForColumn:@"lbGoalId"]),
   @"groupId" : @([rs intForColumn:@"groupId"]),
   // etc.
};
```

Comment: Understanding analyser is really very tough. Problem was in below and it's shows upper line.. Anyways Thanx the problem was in extra nil.... :)

Answer (score 0):

When creating dictionary you are trying to set `nil` in between. When I try to execute this I donot face any warning

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getLSBGoalList
{
//    int userId = [[[AppManager sharedAppManager].userInfo objectForKey:USER_ID] intValue];

//    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM tblLBGoal WHERE userId = %@ ORDER BY groupId", @""];

   MyClass *rs=self;
    NSMutableArray *arrLSBGoals = [NSMutableArray array];
    while([rs next])
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:[rs intForColumn:@"lbGoalId"]], @"lbGoalId",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:[rs intForColumn:@"groupId"]], @"groupId",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:[rs intForColumn:@"userId"]], @"userId",
                              [rs stringForColumn:@"uuid"],@"uuid",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:[rs intForColumn:@"dataSyncType"]], @"dataSyncType",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:[rs intForColumn:@"idealValue"]], @"idealValue",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:[rs intForColumn:@"targetValue"]], @"targetValue",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:[rs intForColumn:@"isTargetSet"]], @"isTargetSet",nil];

        [arrLSBGoals addObject:dict];
    }
    return arrLSBGoals;
}

- (BOOL)next{
    return YES;
}

- (int)intForColumn:(NSString *)str{
    return 0;
}
- (NSString *)stringForColumn:(NSString *)str{
    return @"";
}
```